# How to say my ass

Tags: academic-japanese

RECENTLY  I found word meaning my ass as an disbelief in japanese but somehow it doesn't show up on the internet 
.it sounds  like this janentaro.

Comment: There's no question in this post? Also, where I am from the phrase "my ass" isn't used all that often so I'm not quite sure what sort of situation you are envisioning. You could make this more clear to people unfamiliar with that slang by describing a situation, and also where you think you found this word.

Comment: @katatahito:  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/my%20ass!

Comment: academic Japanese tag? this seems like a troll. vote to delete.

Comment: Possible troll post - talks about academic Japanese for the phrase "my ass"

Comment: I didn't realise it's a a troll post .I'm new though

Answer (score 1):

Aじゃねーよ means "NOT A".  There are many ways to conjugate this sentence that sound like what you may have heard： じゃねぇんだよ,じゃねぇんだぞ,じゃねぇだろう...etc

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cqvlMpv8YsM&t=106s around 1:42